# extending Object.prototype.myNewMethod over all my Node application

Tags: object, prototype, module, node.js, extend

I've just started at NodeJs so I am not familiar whether this is a good practice or not, sorry :(

I have my Object implementation which add a merge method to all objects I create so I can merge to different objects in one.

```
Object.prototype.merge = function(source){
    //...my code here
    return this;
}
```

So I would like to know how I could make this available to all the modules inside my Node app?

I've read on [this excellent book](http://visionmedia.github.com/masteringnode/book.html#Creating-Modules) that I could create a **module** for that and then call `utils.merge(obj1, obj2)` for example.

But even so I'd rather keep using my object's implementation instead, and simply call `obj1.merge(obj2)`

is there any way to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your implementation in a file and require it before anything else in the main `.js` file of your app.

- `objectmerge.js`;

  Object.prototype.merge = function(){ /*body*/};
- `main.js`:

  require('objectmerge.js');
  // go on with your code

This way, your `objectmerge.js` script will run first and modify the global `Object` before anything else. However, I'd recommend against it, as it isn't common practice (and that it allows you to use `foo.merge(bar)` in a file where you haven't explicitly defined `Object.prototype.merge`.